# Masking sensitive data in a file using regex

Tags: java, security, data-masking

We have a web-based Java ESB application that is used for data transformation and processing. In the dashboard, the user has the ability to view/download the incoming source data file.

For PII data compliance, we have a requirement to mask the sensitive data information in it based on regex. The user will define multiple regex patterns in the application, we need to scan the source file for these regex patterns and mask the sensitive data.

1. The incoming source file can be of any type (CSV, XML, JSON, Excel, PDF) having any layout.
2. The sensitive information (credit card #, SSN #) can be present anywhere in the file and in few cases, we don't have information where these fields are located in the file.

As a solution, we have tried [Chlorine-Finder API](https://github.com/dataApps/chlorine-finder), it works well for a few cases but has the following issues:

1. It doesn't work with the binary (Excel and PDF) files.
2. We need to convert the file into STRING before masking which has a performance impact (in terms of the memory usage) for bigger files.

So, we are looking for alternate options. Are there any other Java libraries that can be used for data masking - the one that works with the binary files as well? Any other suggestions?